# android: writing to file from testcase

Tags: android, file, permissions

I am trying to write to a file from my testcase. I am trying to write to internal storage but it gives permission error. 
`

```
Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream =  context.getAssets().open("myFile");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            File f = new File(context.getFilesDir(),"outfile");
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;

            while((length=inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
            }

            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

            return f;
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }`
```

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/package/files/outfile (Permission denied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the context. For getting the app context instead of context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext(); use getTargetContext(()

Answer (score 0):

You can use Junit's temporary folder to simulate local storage.

```
TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = getTemporaryFolder();
File outFile = temporaryFolder.newFile("outFile");
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
```

Comment: I having issue with the outfile. See my question edited. I am able to read from my assets folder

Comment: I edited my answer, you can use a temporary folder to simulate local storage on your test.